# In Joomla - limit menu depth for specific item?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

In Joomla 3 - if my menu structure is:

- About

  - Sub Item 1
  - Sub item 2
- Products

  - Sub Item 1

    - item 1
  - Sub Item 2

How can I limit the depth of the menu? For Instance if I only wanted "About" to go to level 1, and "Products" to go to level 3? Is there anyway I can set it individually?

I understand I could use:
"display: none;" for the sub menu.

However - this doesn't work using a responsive framework such as foundation or bootstrap as the "has-dropdown" class triggers the dropdown menus for mobile.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried unpublishing `Sub item 2` from the menu management in the joomla backend?

Comment: Then the Joomla SEF is gone and the page is unreachable:
/about/faq - it is no longer that page

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Leave your menu as-is and create a second menu with aliases to the first menu with only the pages you want. This is the method I use, where the first menu is the site map and the second (and third, etc.) are for navigation menus.
2. On the module you're using to display the menu there is an option to limit the level of the links. This applies to the entire menu, though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you need to un-publish the sub-menu items under the top level menu item About you do want to be displayed.  I know you responded to *ilias* saying this would break SEF, but that isn't true.  Go ahead and un-publish the sub-menu item faq, and refresh the homepage to verify sub-menu is not longer appearing.  Now, navigate to the url http://www.mysite.com/about/faq and see the page still be rendered.

The un-publish is used by the mod_menu module during the HTML rendering process, the MVC path created is still valid.  This is a great "best practice" to add SEF to dedicated pages with no menu header, to create an unpublished menu entry to manage the SEF silently.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Hi Brian - it doesn't work in this case:

1. Unpublished FAQ Sub
http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a32jxfq16

2. Screen Shot shows unpublished
http://awesomescreenshot.com/02c2jxe654

Comment: @iamrobert can you post the actual url for me to try and navigate to?

Comment: @iamrobert a second question, when you navigate to http://www.mysite.com/about is the page loading properly?

Comment: Hi Brian - URLs:
1. http://vf2.taichungdesigner.com/index.php/en/about
2. http://vf2.taichungdesigner.com/index.php/en/about/faq

http://imgur.com/E7o7sZ5 - it shows an error whenever I disable it. Perhaps - its linked to Joomla language manager or FLEXIcontent.

Comment: On your global configuration section, are both the SEF and SEF Rewrite enabled in the backend

Comment: Yes - http://awesomescreenshot.com/0652k3yxec - and as soon as I unpublish - the 404 error returns

Comment: @iamrobert Apologies but after testing locally I realized I made mistake.  The key is to replicate the menu taxonomy you want to SEF having all the menu items published, but not assigning them to a menu module.  So in this case, you could create a new menutype of Placement or SEF, adding both the About menu item and Faq sub-menu items as published (you can completely remove/trash the Faq sub-menu item from the main menu assigned to a mod_menu module.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - as we are using Foundation 3.2.5 and Joomla - here's our solution:

1. In J3.2 - you can add a class to the a of each menu - we added "off"
2. We wrote the css for a.off to: `.dropdown.off {display: none !important;} 
   .top-bar ul>li.has-dropdown a.off:after  {display: none;}
   .top-bar ul>li.has-dropdown a.off {
   padding-right: 10px;
   }`
3. As we are using foundation 3.2 we rewrote the js - so that when the class a.off is there - it will go to the actual link: `/*
   jQuery Foundation Top Bar 2.0.4
   http://foundation.zurb.com
   Copyright 2012, ZURB
   Free to use under the MIT license.
   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
   */
   /*jslint unparam: true, browser: true, indent: 2 */
   (function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r={index:0,initialized:!1},i={init:function(n){return this.each(function(){r=e.extend(r,n),r.$w=e(t),r.$topbar=e("nav.top-bar"),r.$section=r.$topbar.find("section"),r.$titlebar=r.$topbar.children("ul:first");var s=e("<div class='top-bar-js-breakpoint'/>").appendTo("body");r.breakPoint=s.width(),s.remove(),r.initialized||(i.assemble(),r.initialized=!0),r.height||i.largestUL(),r.$topbar.parent().hasClass("fixed")&&e("body").css("padding-top",r.$topbar.outerHeight()),e(".top-bar .toggle-topbar").off("click.fndtn").on("click.fndtn",function(e){e.preventDefault(),i.breakpoint()&&(r.$topbar.toggleClass("expanded"),r.$topbar.css("min-height","")),r.$topbar.hasClass("expanded")||(r.$section.css({left:"0%"}),r.$section.find(">.name").css({left:"100%"}),r.$section.find("li.moved").removeClass("moved"),r.index=0)}),e(".top-bar .has-dropdown>a:not(.off)").off("click.fndtn").on("click.fndtn",function(t){(Modernizr.touch||i.breakpoint())&&t.preventDefault();if(i.breakpoint()){var n=e(this),s=n.closest("li");r.index+=1,s.addClass("moved"),r.$section.css({left:-(100*r.index)+"%"}),r.$section.find(">.name").css({left:100*r.index+"%"}),n.siblings("ul").height(r.height+r.$titlebar.outerHeight(!0)),r.$topbar.css("min-height",r.height+r.$titlebar.outerHeight(!0)*2)}}),e(t).on("resize.fndtn.topbar",function(){i.breakpoint()||r.$topbar.css("min-height","")}),e(".top-bar .has-dropdown .back").off("click.fndtn").on("click.fndtn",function(t){t.preventDefault();var n=e(this),i=n.closest("li.moved"),s=i.parent();r.index-=1,r.$section.css({left:-(100*r.index)+"%"}),r.$section.find(">.name").css({left:100*r.index+"%"}),r.index===0&&r.$topbar.css("min-height",0),setTimeout(function(){i.removeClass("moved")},300)})})},breakpoint:function(){return r.$w.width()<r.breakPoint},assemble:function(){r.$section.detach(),r.$section.find(".has-dropdown>a").each(function(){var t=e(this),n=t.siblings(".dropdown"),r=e('<li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="#"></a></h5></li>');r.find("h5>a").html(t.html()),n.prepend(r)}),r.$section.appendTo(r.$topbar)},largestUL:function(){var t=r.$topbar.find("section ul ul"),n=t.first(),i=0;t.each(function(){e(this).children("li").length>n.children("li").length&&(n=e(this))}),n.children("li").each(function(){i+=e(this).outerHeight(!0)}),r.height=i}};e.fn.foundationTopBar=function(t){if(i[t])return i[t].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1));if(typeof t=="object"||!t)return i.init.apply(this,arguments);e.error("Method "+t+" does not exist on jQuery.foundationTopBar")};if(e(".sticky").length>0){var s=e(".sticky").length?e(".sticky").offset().top:0,o=e(t);o.scroll(function(){o.scrollTop()>=s?e(".sticky").addClass("fixed"):o.scrollTop()<s&&e(".sticky").removeClass("fixed")})}})(jQuery,this);`